# How to add MapChildren for each element in a Collection in Windows Phone 8.1 project using C#?

Tags: c#

I am a beginner in Windows Phone development, while trying to develop a map based application, I am stuck how to add a MapIcon or any MapChildren for a no. of locations stored in a database file.
I have successfully retrieved the data collection from the database, further i don't know how to add a mapIcon for each entry
    try
            {
                double latitude = myposition.Coordinate.Point.Position.Latitude;
                double longitude = myposition.Coordinate.Point.Position.Longitude;
                Collection bins = new Collection();       //collection of class Dustbin
                bins = DustbinViewModel.GetDefault().GetItem(latitude, longitude);      //database query using ViewModels..It is working
                msgbox = new MessageDialog("Dustbins retrieved");
                await msgbox.ShowAsync();
                string msg = "";
                foreach (Dustbin d in bins)
                {
                    msg = msg + d.Id + "\n";
                }
                msgbox = new MessageDialog(msg);        //Just for checking whether the data is recieved or not
                await msgbox.ShowAsync();

```
            int i = 1;
            foreach (Dustbin d in bins)
            {
                Geopoint point = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition
                {
                    Latitude = d.Latitude,
                    Longitude = d.Latitude
                });
                /*var shape = new MapIcon
                {
                    Title = "Dustbin:" + i,
                    Location = point,
                    Image = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/dustbin.png")),
                    NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(0.5, 0.5),
                    ZIndex = 5,
                };
                MyMap.MapElements.Add(shape);*/
                Image image = new Image();
                image.Width = 40;
                image.Height = 40;
                BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
                bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/location.png");
                image.Source = bitmapImage;
                MapControl.SetLocation(image, point);
                MapControl.SetNormalizedAnchorPoint(image, new Point(0.25, 0.9));
                MyMap.Children.Add(image);
                i++;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            msgbox = new MessageDialog("Something went wrong !! Please try again later."+ex.Message);
            await msgbox.ShowAsync();
        }
```

As I am new to this field, I will be thankful to your answers..

Answer (score 1):

```
 BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
 bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/location.png");
 image.Source = bitmapImage;
 MapControl.SetLocation(image, point);
 MapControl.SetNormalizedAnchorPoint(image, new Point(0.25, 0.9));
 MyMap.Children.Add(image);
```

Just add

```
MapControl.SetLocation(bitmapImage, point);  
MyMap.Children.Add(bitmapImage);
MapControl.SetNormalizedAnchorPoint(bitmapImage, new Point(0.25, 0.9));
```